# TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str when I join items in list

Tags: python, typeerror

I am reading list items, joining items in list to perform some action on it

```
json_data=open("example2__test.json").read()
test_action = json.loads(json_data)
for input_action in test_action:
    print " ".join(input_action["logs"])
```

This works fine.

Now I am using `test_action` in some other for loop

```
for input_action in test_action:
    for record in data:
        res = {}
        item = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' '," ".join(record["logs"]))
        input_action = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]',' '," ".join(input_action["logs"]))
        item = stopwords_removal(item)
```

I am getting this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-d42d327f3292> in <module>()
     11 #         temp = " ".join(input_action["logs"])
     12 
---> 13         input_action = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]',' '," ".join(input_action["logs"]))
     14         item = stopwords_removal(item)

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Why it gives this error I cant understand. Here `" ".join(record["logs"])` also performs same action but it does not give this error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: it is list, also same `input_action` i could join in example2_test.json

Comment: `for input_action in test_action.values():` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for input_action in test_action:
    for record in data:
        res = {}
        item = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' '," ".join(record["logs"]))
        #problem in below line
        input_action = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]',' '," ".join(input_action["logs"]))
        item = stopwords_removal(item)
```

The problem is that you have reassigned input_action as the result of `re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]',' '," ".join(input_action["logs"]))`. In the first pass of the loop through "data", input_action may have been a dictionary. But in your second pass, it is most definitely a string, and thus `input_action["logs"]` throws that error. The issue happens in the 2nd iteration of inner loop, not the first.

Edit: **bottom line**, You are mutating the `input_action` variable on each pass of inner loop, and if it runs more than 1, it will fail.

Comment: no @jonrsharpe, that would only be true if the inner loop only ran once.

Comment: even if I dont reasign, and just print `" ".join(input_action["logs"])` still it gives same error

Comment: In that case, can you provide some additional information of your data that you are using? @Programming_crazy